# Firebase Functions for Firestore Failing due to NanoMatch Issue

Tags: function, firebase, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to cloud functions and was testing this sample code https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore
This fails to execute due to an error from nanomatch. Looking at nanomatch repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/micromatch/nanomatch/issues/15) This is a listed issue and reverting back to 1.2.9 takes care of this error.

I am trying to fix this on my end - but how do I do this? Can somebody guide me on this. Thank you for the help.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addQmark' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/nanomatch/lib/compilers.js:92:15)
    at Object.visit (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/snapdragon/lib/compiler.js:129:15)
    at Object.mapVisit (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/snapdragon/lib/compiler.js:143:12)
    at Object.compile (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/snapdragon/lib/compiler.js:168:10)
    at Snapdragon.compile (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/snapdragon/index.js:156:32)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/micromatch/index.js:786:23
    at memoize (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/micromatch/index.js:859:13)
    at Function.micromatch.compile (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/micromatch/index.js:783:10)
    at create (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/micromatch/index.js:686:25)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/micromatch/index.js:695:16
```

Comment: Got the same error right now. (Exactly the same timing as you here in Japan). 
Seems some issue on the firebase side..

Comment: i am also facing same error in india

Comment: same here, in Japan too.

Comment: Los Angeles, so looks like its not limited to a Geo area

Comment: same here in japan . I use typescript

Comment: Same issue also in Antarctica

Comment: It looks like this is a temporary problem with a package called nanomatch: https://github.com/micromatch/nanomatch/issues/15

Comment: Same issue in Singapore

Comment: @DougStevenson May we know what is the solution?

Comment: @DougStevenson How to avoid this problem? Our app completely depends on cloud functions.

Comment: This was fixed right after it was reported. Please see my comment below.

Comment: Don't downgrade nanomatch, just reinstall. It was fixed a long time ago.

Comment: Update: As of 3:12 Pm Singapore Time 27 June 2018. The issue with addQMark no longer exists with my Firebase Cloud Functions Firestore.

Comment: It also broke GCP Cloud Functions. Seems like it was worldwide. Simply redeploying over an existing Cloud Function is not enough. I had to completely delete it first and deploy a fresh one since it seems that dependency is being cached. Pulled my hair out for a couple hours thinking I had miscoded something. Terrible...

Comment: @jonschlinkert Thank you for the edit and update. I asked this question not for support on nanomatch but trying to understand how to revert back to the old version on Firebase. I will be more careful in the future. Thanks once again.

Comment: FWIW, this was fixed for me after waiting a while and redeploying my Firebase functions. I think the posts about rolling back versions, upgrading etc. to fix things are wrong: this has no impact as this was a fix that Google had to make on their end.

Comment: It seems solved. I just re-deployed my functions then works fine. Maybe Firebase team worked.

Comment: @PrafulHalakhandi understood, thank you for your comment. I should have worded my initial comment more considerately. I was appreciative of you creating the conversation here so that we could reach as many people as possible, allowing me to then redirect them to the main issue/ticket on GitHub. Thank you for taking the time to create this, and apologies for the problems this caused.

Answer (score 1):

### THIS BUG WAS FIXED

The version that caused the bug was reverted right when this issue [was reported on GitHub](https://github.com/micromatch/nanomatch/issues/15), which was within minutes of it being released. To get the fix, just reinstall. You might need to delete node_modules and/or lockfiles first, to ensure cached versions aren't used by NPM. This conversation belongs on GitHub, so that we can respond to user feedback. I found this by chance. StackOverflow is not for support).

Edit 2: it appears that firebase-admin itself needs to re-install dependencies as well. I'm looking into how to make that happen.

Please report and check issues on GitHub, where the codebase is and where this discussion belongs.

Visit https://github.com/micromatch/nanomatch/issues/15 for more info.

Comment: I have reinstalled the node _ modules but still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem "Thumbnail URL not saved to firestore. Cannot read property 'addQmark' of undefined"
Started today morning when I upgraded to the latest firebase-tools@3.19.1 
At first thought was issue with my code, but after rollbacking my code the situation persisted. 
Rolled back to firebase-tools@3.19.0 and the situation got fixed.
There is a bug in the latest firebase-tools

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

npm install nanomatch@1.2.9 -S

Answer (score 0):

Firebase team is probably/hopefully redeploying all functions without the broken nanomatch package, but for me following the advice from @abhi and redeploying immediately solved the issue!

```
npm install nanomatch@1.2.9 -S
firebase deploy --only functions
```

(npm install in the functions folder!)

Answer (score 0):

just rollback to older version
npm install -g firebase-tools@3.19.0